# Fortran functions and return values

Tags: fortran

How can I write a function in Fortran which takes both input and output as arguments? For example:

```
fun(integer input,integer output)
```

I want to make use of the output value. I have tried something like this but the output variable is not holding the value.

Specifically, I am calling a C function from Fortran which takes input and output as parameters. I am able to pass input values successfully, but the output variable is not acquiring a value.

Comment: Can you paste you fortran and c signatures please

Answer (score 5):

In Fortran, your `fun()` is called a subroutine. A function is a value-returning thing like this:

```
sin_of_x = sin(x)
```

So your first decision is which approach your Fortran code will take. You probably want to use a subroutine.  Then sort out the intent of your arguments.

Answer (score 4):

An example. if you want a function that returns void you should use a subroutine instead.

```
function foo(input, output)
    implicit none
    integer :: foo
    integer, intent(in) :: input
    integer, intent(out) :: output

    output = input + 3
    foo = 0
end function

program test
    implicit none
    integer :: a, b, c, foo

    b = 5
    a = foo(b, c)

    print *,a,b, c

end program
```

If you are calling a C routine, then the signature makes use of references.

```
$ cat test.f90 
program test
    implicit none
    integer :: a, b, c, foo

    b = 5
    a = foo(b, c)

    print *,a,b, c

end program 

$ cat foo.c 
#include <stdio.h>
int foo_(int *input, int *output) {
    printf("I'm a C routine\n"); 
    *output = 3 + *input;

    return 0;
}


$ g95 -c test.f90 
$ gcc -c foo.c 
$ g95 test.o foo.o 
$ ./a.out 
I'm a C routine
 0 5 8
```

if you use strings, things gets messy.

Comment: So is the only practical difference between a Fortran function and subroutine that the subroutine doesn't return a value?

Comment: @naught101: No, there are other differences, but I have two years of rust accumulated so I don't remember the details anymore.